# Can we use 4d hemisphere for transformation between 3d hyperbolic models

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

In hyperbolic geometry 3d hemisphere is used for transformation between 2d disc models of Klein and Poincare. Can we use the  4d hemisphere for transformation between 3d Poincare and Klein models

Comment: Your question is rather vaguely stated. Can you be more explicit either with concrete definitions or references?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Relation5models.png

Comment: This shape explains transformation between 2D disc models. If we use 4D hemisphere, could we transform object between 3D hyperbolic Poincare and Beltrami ball models?

Comment: For example,  streographicly project  of the vertices of an 3d cube in Poincare model  from 0,0,0,-1 to 4D sphere then delete w coordinates would give the beltrami coordinate of the cube?

Comment: Namely, would this picture work in one upper dimension?